# Is there a defined non-trivial chromosome number distribution for a given kingdom?

Tags: evolution, chromosome

I'm pretty aware of the mechanisms for chromosome number evolution in specific groups (e.g. inside a given genus). Nevertheless, looking at a broader scale (e.g. in the Metazoa kingdom), is there a well defined distribution for the frequency of occurrence of chromosome numbers?

For example, are species with small chromosome numbers more frequent than those with large chromosome numbers? If so, is there some sort of scaling relationship between number of species and number of chromosomes?

Comment: [Page 445](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SlI4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA453&lpg=PA453&dq=chromosome+number+histogram&source=bl&ots=ZpH6Pmr-Yy&sig=cOpmg-W_I5jaXIhBlnM4NGbsoU0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKttCdg9DTAhUMyGMKHeNdDgYQ6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=chromosome%20number%20histogram&f=false) for a start.

Comment: Not in my country...